# Qt SQL Database Autocomplete

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, autocomplete

I am trying to create an autocompleting `lineEdit` using values from my SQLite database. The problem is that there is no autocomplete in the `lineEdit`. The code I am using is below:

```
AutoComplete();
QCompleter *Account_completer = new QCompleter(AccountList);
QCompleter *Product_completer = new QCompleter(ProductList);
Account_completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
Product_completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
ui->lineEdit_Invoice_Account->setCompleter(Account_completer);
ui->lineEdit_Invoice_Product->setCompleter(Product_completer);
```

My autocomplete procedure is below:

```
QSqlQuery Account;
QSqlQuery Product;
switch(ui->comboBox_Invoice_Account_Search->currentIndex())
{
    case 0:
        Account.prepare("SELECT Customer_ID FROM Customer");
        Account.exec();
        break;
    case 1:
        Account.prepare("SELECT Company_Name FROM Customer");
        break;
    case 2:
        Account.prepare("SELECT Company_Owner FROM Customer");
        break;
    case 3:
        Account.prepare("SELECT Phone_Number FROM Customer");
        break;
    case 4:
        Account.prepare("SELECT BULSTAT FROM Customer");
        break;
}
switch(ui->comboBox_Invoice_Product_Search->currentIndex())
{
    case 0:
        Product.prepare("SELECT Product_CODE FROM Product");
        break;
    case 1:
        Product.prepare("SELECT Product_Name FROM Product");
        break;
}
Account.exec();
qDebug() << "SQL QUERY Account:" << Account.executedQuery();
qDebug() << "SQL ERROR Account:" << Account.lastError();
while(Account.next())
    AccountList = Account.value(0).toStringList();
Product.exec();
qDebug() << "SQL QUERY Product:" << Product.executedQuery();
qDebug() << "SQL ERROR Product:" << Product.lastError();
while(Product.next())
    ProductList = Product.value(0).toStringList();
for(int x = 0; x <= Account.size(); x++)
    qDebug() << AccountList.at(x).toLocal8Bit().constData() << endl;
for(int y = 0; y <= Product.size(); y++)
    qDebug() <<  ProductList.at(y).toLocal8Bit().constData() << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you keep deleting your questions after getting replies, we will not  help. It is a bit rude and time wasting.

Comment: I Apologize for that.

Comment: No worries. Out of curiosity: why did you delete that answer? What was your finding? You missed that next() call that I mentioned or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you have initialized your database connection and `QSqlQuery` correctly. But There is no need to populate the `QCompleter` manually. You can use a model like `QSqlTableModel` and use `QCompleter::setCompletionColumn` to set a specific column to be searched by completer :

```
QSqlTableModel * model = new QSqlTableModel(this,db);
model->setTable( "Customer" );
model->select();

QCompleter *Account_completer = new QCompleter(model, this);
completer->setCompletionColumn(someIndex);
```

You can define the column index `someIndex` on your own, probably here by the selected index of a combo box.

Comment: if I am not mistaken: afterwards, you still have to connect a QLineEdit to this completer, p.e. `ui->somelineedit->setCompleter(Account_completer);`, and link it to the mapper?

Comment: @Wim Yes you should  assign the completer to a line edit.

Comment: thx :-) I tried it at https://github.com/vvim/BT_deelnemers/commit/1895144677a2862ff085175d254b11035d73482b (lines 401-403 of the cpp) but it failed to work. Maybe link to the mapper as well?